# How to use @componentScan in @springBootTest class

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

I am creating a test class for my spring application. The main application has following configurations

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.graphql.demo"})
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I need to scan that graphql package for my tests. I tried by added the @ComponentScan in my test class.

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class,MockitoExtension.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.graphql.demo"})
@SpringBootTest
public class SampleTestClass {
// my code
}
```

But it seems it is not reading that graphql packages which I need. How can I scan the base packages in spring boot test?

Answer (score 1):

A single `@SpringBootTest` should be enough. `@SpringBootTest` will find the nearest `@SpringBootApplication` (looking up in the packages hierarchy), and use all of it's configuration.

Make sure that your test resides in the sub-package of the main class (`MyApplication`) package.

If your `MyApplication` resides in `com.graphql.demo`, your test should be in `com.graphql.demo.**`, otherwise the `@SpringBootTest` won't find the main class and it's configuration.